# How to access material.resolution in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am following this tutorial, and I'm trying to draw a thick line based on different coordinates.
https://github.com/leighhalliday/google-maps-threejs/blob/main/pages/car.js

My code stuck in here

```
trackRef.current.material.resolution.copy(
  overlayRef.current.getViewportSize()
);
```

because there's no 'resolution' in material.
My code for thick line is this:

```
const lineGeometry = new LineGeometry().setPositions(positions);
const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xff0000,
  linewidth: 8,
});
const line = new Line2(lineGeometry, lineMaterial);
```

How do I access to material.resolution or does anyone know any other way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [LineMaterial](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r152/examples/jsm/lines/LineMaterial.js) not `LineBasicMaterial`. Both classes are two different things. Only `LineMaterial` can be used for rendering wide lines. Notice that you have to import this material separately like so:

```js
import { LineMaterial } from 'three/addons/lines/LineMaterial.js';
```